# Spatial representation of Data in R?

Tags: r, sp

I'm a new users of spatial analyses packages in R.
I have created a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame which contains a number of rectangular polygons that i named "Square1" to "Square64".
Until now there is no problem i can plot these polygons on a map. The problem is that i have a data.frame that contains the number of vesels in each "Square_i" (i=1 to 64) polygon, but i don't know how to relate each polygons in my SpatialPolygonsDataFrame object to the data.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you post your data? Or at least the structure of your SpatialPolygonsDataFrame?

Answer (score 1):

In a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame, the polygons and the dataframe should automatically link up through the names of the polygons or the row.names of the dataframe. Assuming your SpatialPolygonsDataFrame is called `spdf` take a look at:

```
row.names(spdf@data)
names(spdf@polygons)
```